# In g++, how do I know exactly which .so file was linked when using the -l flag

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Let's say by accident, there are two `foo.so` files that are in different directories. If I use `-lfoo` in g++, how do I know which `foo.so` has been linked?

Comment: Try using  the [`ldd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) command.

Comment: oh wow thanks!! that did it. I have a second simple question though. If I can't get rid of the .so that the program is linking but still hope that the program links the other .so file, is there a way to tell g++ to do that?

Comment: Sure, just add the full path to the compilation command, without the `-l` part.